# Jcarousel loading time issue on Safari/Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, jcarousel

I am facing a serious loading time issue with **jcarousel** on **Chrome** and **Safari**. On Firefox the page loads in under 1 second, in Chrome and Safari it is taking up to 10 seconds.

The carousel is being displayed on a homepage that has many tabs. On Chrome/Safari, the page opens and display all tabs except the carousel tab, but freezes for 10 seconds until the carousel tab is displayed. So I tried moving the block that displays the carousel to inside an Ajax call (the Ajax call writes the li elements and sends them back to the response), thinking that the carousel tab could take as long as it wants to open as long as the other elements were loaded first at least, but to no avail (page still freezes).

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"../ajaxServices/display_showcase.php",
    success : function(data){
    $('#mycarousel').html(data);
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 1
    });  
}
});
```

I noticed two things:

1. If I remove the $('#mycarousel').jcarousel call from the response, the page opens rapidly.
2. If I remove the images tags from the li (inside the ajax php file), the page opens rapidly - However, I am facing the issue even when there is one single image in the carousel and note that all images are relatively small in size (< 40 kb in general).

What is weird is that on Firefox it is working great...

Any help on how to debug or resolve this issue would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure your images have all been given width and height in pixels.

Secondly, also try to wrap your ajax call in a window.load statement as such:
    `$(window).load(function() {
        // Your jcarousel call
    });`

If you are using jquery.carousel.js, then search for blocks that are intended to fix some old but now obsolete browser conditions. For example, around line 184, comment the following in jquery.carousel.js:

```
/*if ($.browser.safari) {
  this.buttons(false, false);
  $(window).bind('load', function() { self.setup(); });
} else */
  this.setup();
```

and around line 858 comment the following:

```
/*if (p == 'marginRight' && $.browser.safari) {
        var old = {'display': 'block', 'float': 'none', 'width': 'auto'}, oWidth, oWidth2;

        $.swap(el, old, function() { oWidth = el.offsetWidth; });

        old['marginRight'] = 0;
        $.swap(el, old, function() { oWidth2 = el.offsetWidth; });

        return oWidth2 - oWidth;
        }*/
```

Comment: 1. I already have my ajax call inside a document.ready statement (and we have also tried .load instead).
2. There was only a width on the images and we have added the height, but still no use.
3. I have removed the first block mentioned, however I could not find the second block and there is no other reference to $.browser.safari in the file.

The issue is still the same.

Comment: I see. Maybe it's i.browser.safari instead of $.browser.safari ?

Comment: There is no reference to i.browser.safari in the file either. I think we're going to go to the extreme solution and replace the whole jcarousel with some other slider as chances of solving this one are looking dim. Thanks for the help!